# eclipse internal web browser could not enter anything

Tags: java, eclipse

I was doing a login website and when i run it, i could not enter any text. I'm using eclipse internal web browser and using apache tomcat 7 server. It shows a textbox but i could not enter anything.

[See Image here](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=ed398e95c5e7e38d&id=ED398E95C5E7E38D%2147421&v=3&ithint=photo,PNG&authkey=!AKYL6UQLZWpDqJo)

[image]

```
 <form action="/JavaProject/Login" method="post">

        Enter username <input type="text"  name="accountUsername" />
        <br>
        Enter password <input type ="password" name ="accountPassword"/>

        <br>

        <input type ="submit" value ="submit"/>
        </form>
```

When I run it, i could not enter any text at all.

Comment: Copy the url that you get in the eclipse browser and paste in any other browser that you have and please update the status.

Comment: It works in chrome, as well as firefox just that the internal web browser doesnt work

Comment: then please try it from there itself. it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

What is your eclipse version and how are your machine resources at the time of running the internal browser?